# How to plot two histograms on the same axis scale?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, histogram

I have two dataframes: dataf1, dataf2. They have the same structure and columns.
3 columns names are A,B,C. And they both have 50 rows.
I would like to plot the histogram of column B on dataf1 and dataf2. I can plot two histograms separately but they are not of the same scale. I would like to know how to either put them on the same histogram using different colors or plot two histograms of the same scale?

```
ggplot() + aes(dataf1$B)+ geom_histogram(binwidth=1, colour="black",fill="white") 
ggplot() + aes(dataf2$B)+ geom_histogram(binwidth=1, colour="black", fill="white")
```

Comment: Don't use `$` inside of `aes()`!! Also, please edit the code into your question (with formatting!) it is difficult to read in the comments.

Comment: Hey, do you have any sample data? maybe the first few lines of data f1 and data f2?

Comment: In theory, all you have to do is join the two dataframes together and add a column for f1/f2 - Then just group by that column by setting the colour to that column name - this will draw both on the same graphs

Answer (score 5):

Combine your data into a single data frame with a new column marking which data frame the data originally came from. Then use that new column for the fill aesthetic for your plot.

```
data1$source="Data 1"
data2$source="Data 2"

dat_combined = rbind(data1, data2)
```

You haven't provided sample data, so here are a few examples of possible plots, using the built-in `iris` data frame. In the plots below, `dat` is analogous to `dat_combined`, `Petal.Width` is analogous to `B`, and `Species` is analogous to `source`.

```
dat = subset(iris, Species != "setosa") # We want just two species

ggplot(dat, aes(Petal.Width, fill=Species)) + 
  geom_histogram(position="identity", colour="grey40", alpha=0.5, binwidth=0.1)

ggplot(dat, aes(Petal.Width, fill=Species)) + 
  geom_histogram(position="dodge", binwidth=0.1)

ggplot(dat, aes(Petal.Width, fill=Species)) + 
  geom_histogram(position="identity", colour="grey40", binwidth=0.1) +
  facet_grid(Species ~ .)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As Zheyuan says, you just need to set the y limits for each plot to get them on the same scale. With `ggplot2`, one way to do this is with the `lims` command (though `scale_y_continuous` and `coord_cartesian` also work, albeit slightly differently). You also should **never** use `data$column` indside `aes()`. Instead, use the `data` argument for the data frame and unquoted column names inside `aes()`. Here's an example with some built-in data.

```
p1 = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) + geom_histogram() + lims(y = c(0, 13))
p2 = ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length)) + geom_histogram() + lims(y = c(0, 13))

gridExtra::grid.arrange(p1, p2, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Two get two histograms on the same plot, the best way is to combine your data frames. A guess, without seeing what your data looks like:

```
dataf = rbind(dataf1["B"], dataf2["B"])
dafaf$source = c(rep("f1", nrow(dataf1)), rep("f2", nrow(dataf2))

ggplot(dataf, aes(x = B, fill = source)) + 
    geom_histogram(position = "identity", alpha = 0.7)
```